Sitecore Form is not working on my local instance, Sitecore version 10.2
I have a task to implement sitecore forms out of the box, and when I try to open the forms from the Desktop, it gives me the following error, any solutions?

and the following text is a message from log file:
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not locate type 'Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Models.SearchTextBoxRenderingModel, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client'. Model reference: 'Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Models.SearchTextBoxRenderingModel, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client'
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ModelLocator.GetModelFromTypeName(String typeName, String model, Boolean throwOnTypeCreationError)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromRenderingItem.Process(GetModelArgs args)
  at (Object , Object )
  at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
  at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
  at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel()
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model()
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault[T,TResult](T source, Func`2 resultGetter)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model()
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)


Here are steps to troubleshoot and potentially resolve this issue:

Check Assembly References
Ensure that the "Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.dll" assembly is present in the bin directory of your Sitecore instance.
(usually located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot<SitecoreInstance>\bin)

Verify Sitecore Experience Forms Installation
Confirm that the Sitecore Experience Forms module is correctly installed. (Sitecore control panel and check the installed packages to see if the Sitecore Experience Forms module is listed.)
If it's not installed, you might need to reinstall or repair the Sitecore Experience Forms module.

Update or Rebuild the Solution
Check the references to ensure Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client is referenced correctly.
Rebuild the solution to make sure all assemblies are properly compiled and deployed.

Review Log Files
The logs are typically located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot<SitecoreInstance>\App _Data\logs.



It appears that this issue may be due to an assembly version mismatch. Specifically, the version of the assembly referenced in your project may not align with the version expected by Sitecore.
To resolve this, ensure that you are using the correct version of the Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client assembly. Check your project's references and compare them with the versions required by Sitecore to make sure they match.
